# empty set returned as set() in dataframe, how to return is as None or NULL?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function where I initiate a column as an empty set, because I want to append only unique values to it as I'm looping through a list.

However, when no values is added to the set, it will returned as `set()` in the dataframe, whereas I want it to be returning `NULL` or `None`. How should I do that?

Here is a dummy example:

Also this function is designed to work column-wise and to be passed in to `df.apply(, axis=1)` in latter process.

```
row[val_col]='Apple;Banana;Dog'

lookup_map = {'fruit':['Apple'],
'animal':['Cat']}

out_cols = ['fruit','animal']

def assign_vals(row, val_col, out_cols, lookup_map):
  for out_col in out_cols:
        row[out_col] = set()
  vals = row[val_col].split(';')

  for val in vals:
      for out_col in out_cols:
            lookup_vals= lookup_map[out_col]
            for lookup_val in lookup_vals:
                if val in lookup_val:
                    row[out_col].add(lookup_val)

 return ';'.join(row[out_col])
```

This is a contrived example and I haven't debugged it. But just give an idea of my function. If there is a better way to append only unique value to a list without using set, please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Why don't you also post what you *have*, and what you *want it to be* (instead of only posting your attempt and trying to focus on it? refer to XY problem ). IIUC, if you have a list and only want unique values, why not just `set(my_list)` ?

Comment: There is no such thing a `NULL`. If you want it to be `None`, that's fine, but _where_ do you want to see that `None`? You can always do, e.g., `row[out_col] or None`, which will be the row if it's non-empty (non-empty containers are truthy) but `None` if it's empty (empty containers are falsy). But that would just break your code, which assumes that whatever you have in each `row` is something you can use as an iterable. An empty set works for that—`';'.join(set())` returns the empty string `''`, which is fine. `None` will just raise a `TypeError`, which you aren't handling.

Comment: good point, thank you @RafaelC . I changed to initialize with empty list and apply set() to the list after the loop.